# Unix tool for batch file passing to some utillitie

Tags: unix

Question is quite simple

I want to make this kind of bash maddness in a simple way with some shell utillitie:

```
for a in `seq -w 01 25`; do b=`echo $a*.mkv`; c=${b%%.mkv}; ls mkvmerge -o "${c}_mux.mkv" "$c.mkv" "audio/$c.ac3" "audio/$c.ass"; done
```

Idea is just to pass MANY FILES (filenames) into params for some other application FOR multiple command execution. Same like in example just without bash language.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo some list of space separated files; xargs -n 1 /run/some/command
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you want xargs.  Let me know if you have any questions on how to use it.